# How to make text in swing more clear

Tags: java, swing, graphics, fonts

May I ask if it is possible to make the text in swing more clear?

Here's how the word "File" looks in JavaFX:

[image: JavaFX Text]

And here's how it looks in Swing:

[image: Swing Text]

The JavaFX one is absolutely better. Is there any way to make the font in Swing look like the one in JavaFX?

P.S. Both of them are using the font "Microsoft YaHei" at 12px

---

I found a method to open/close anti-alias like

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL,RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_DEFAULT);
    g2d.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    g2d.drawString("File", 50, 50);
}
```

But it seems that it does not work well 
These are my result in testing different fonts: 
Times New Roman
Swing 
["File" in times new roman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK2Ut.png) 
JavaFX 
["File" in times new roman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAMEe.png)

Comment: I'd try flipping anti-aliasing on/off. If that doesn't help, you could create an image from the version in javaFX, and use that for the button in swing

Comment: I have never noticed a problem with displaying text in Swing. Is the problem the Font? I have never heard of the Font you are testing. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem where you use different Fonts to see if they are consistent or if one is definitely worse than the other.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is the problem of my jdk. After I change it to jdk 11, it works well. (it is my font in jdk 11)
[jdk11's "File"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYTfM.png)